# virtualenved python cannot import built-in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, virtualenv

My OS is Linuxmint 17 (essentially Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty), which has a pre-installed python 2.7.6, so when I do:

```
$ python -v
>>> import _sqlite3 
>>> # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

On the other side per project need, I compiled python 2.7.8 from source, I created a virtualenv using command below:

```
virtualenv ~/.venv-python2.7.8/my_project/ -p ~/.localpython-2.7.8/bin/python2.7 --system-site-packages
```

So I get a isolated python/pip/django environment, for sure I get below:

```
(my_project)wayne@wayne-linuxmint17 ~/Projects/adsk_devportal $ which python
/home/wayne/.venv-python2.7.8/my_project/bin/python
(my_project)wayne@wayne-linuxmint17 ~/Projects/adsk_devportal $ python --version
Python 2.7.8
```

However, under the virtualised env, **I cannot import the [python built-in sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)**:

$ python -v

```
>>> import sqlite3
import sqlite3 # directory /home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/sqlite3
# /home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.pyc matches /home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py
import sqlite3 # precompiled from /home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.pyc
# /home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.pyc matches /home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py
import sqlite3.dbapi2 # precompiled from /home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.pyc
# /home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/collections.pyc matches /home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/collections.py
import collections # precompiled from /home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/collections.pyc
dlopen("/home/wayne/.venv-python2.7.8/my_project/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.so", 2);
import _collections # dynamically loaded from /home/wayne/.venv-python2.7.8/my_project/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.so
dlopen("/home/wayne/.venv-python2.7.8/my_project/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so", 2);
import operator # dynamically loaded from /home/wayne/.venv-python2.7.8/my_project/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
# /home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/keyword.pyc matches /home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/keyword.py
import keyword # precompiled from /home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/keyword.pyc
# /home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/heapq.pyc matches /home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/heapq.py
import heapq # precompiled from /home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/heapq.pyc
dlopen("/home/wayne/.venv-python2.7.8/my_project/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so", 2);
import itertools # dynamically loaded from /home/wayne/.venv-python2.7.8/my_project/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so
dlopen("/home/wayne/.venv-python2.7.8/my_project/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so", 2);
import _heapq # dynamically loaded from /home/wayne/.venv-python2.7.8/my_project/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
import thread # builtin
dlopen("/home/wayne/.venv-python2.7.8/my_project/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so", 2);
import datetime # dynamically loaded from /home/wayne/.venv-python2.7.8/my_project/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
dlopen("/home/wayne/.venv-python2.7.8/my_project/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so", 2);
import time # dynamically loaded from /home/wayne/.venv-python2.7.8/my_project/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/home/wayne/.localpython-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

May I know **what is the root cause of this**? What is the easiest way to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Comment: try to run `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"` outside and inside of virtualenv, and compare the results. Maybe some path was not refereced in virtualenv.

Comment: Happened with me recently in Ubuntu, after installing Django in virtualenv, I was not able to import it, but it was importable from normal terminal Python interpreter. So I just chucked the whole virtualenv thing and worked normally from interpreter :)

Comment: @DeepakKumar the problem for me is I must stay in the virtualenv, so I need a solution...

Answer (score 0):

hmmm,

this link might help https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/492#issuecomment-40740803

not sure if it might fix your problem by changing virtualenv

```
diff --git a/virtualenv.py b/virtualenv.py
index 0f5ae79..cfd19bd 100755
--- a/virtualenv.py
+++ b/virtualenv.py
@@ -1191,6 +1191,11 @@ def install_python(home_dir, lib_dir, inc_dir, bin_dir, site_packages, clear, sy
     site_filename_dst = change_prefix(site_filename, home_dir)
     site_dir = os.path.dirname(site_filename_dst)
     writefile(site_filename_dst, SITE_PY)
+    wrapper_path = join(prefix, "lib", py_version, "site-packages")
+    writefile(
+        join(site_dir, 'sitecustomize.py',),
+        "import sys; sys.path.append('%s')" % wrapper_path
+    )
     writefile(join(site_dir, 'orig-prefix.txt'), prefix)
     site_packages_filename = join(site_dir, 'no-global-site-packages.txt')
     if not site_packages:
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.